# SFDX plugin to generate Apex classes from Swagger file is failing to install

Tags: apex, rest-api, salesforcedx, callout, sfdx-plugin

I'm trying to install this plugin https://github.com/muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin , due to some reason it is failing. Please let me know if there is any other way that i can generate classes using swagger file to make callouts from apex.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the same plugin installation command:

> sfdx plugins:install @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin

It appeared to do a number of steps that aren't showing in your screenshot.

> C:>sfdx plugins:install @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin
>   This plugin is not digitally signed and its authenticity cannot be verified. Continue installation y/n?: y
>   Finished digital signature check.
>   warning @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin > oas-raml-converter@1.1.43: Package no longer supported. Use WebAPI Parser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webapi-parser)
>   warning @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin > npm > libcipm@1.6.3: This version mistakenly dropped node@4 compatibility in a semver-patch release. Please stay on 1.6.2 or update to 2 or latest
>   warning @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin > npm > npm-registry-fetch@1.1.1: this version has a breaking change. use 1.1.0 or upgrade to latest
>   warning @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin > oas-raml-converter > swagger-parser > z-schema > core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>   warning @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin > @salesforce/command > @oclif/test > fancy-test > @types/nock@11.1.0: This is a stub types definition. nock provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
>   warning @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin > npm > npm-registry-fetch > make-fetch-happen > socks-proxy-agent > socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
>   warning "@muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin > @oclif/command@1.5.19" has unmet peer dependency "@oclif/plugin-help@^2".
>   Installing plugin @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin... installed v0.4.0

Afterwards, if I do a `sfdx plugins` I get:

> @muenzpraeger/sfdx-plugin 0.4.0

Maybe start by checking your version of the SFDX CLI? My `sfdx version` is reporting

> sfdx-cli/7.27.0-714f62f9c1 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3